# How to sort flutter data to Decending order? Latest on the top

Tags: flutter

can you help me how to sort using this code? Any help is much appreciated.

I want to achieve this output.

```
void main() {
  
  List<String> names = ['Paul','James','Arman'];
  names.sort();
  
  print(names);
 
}
```

**Output:** Arman, James, Paul

I want to apply this code to this chunk of code but I don't know how to apply on this one. This code show in Ascending order and I want to make this descending. Hope you can help me.

```
return ListView.separated(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16.0, top: 16.0),
    shrinkWrap: true,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return ProductItem(
        size: size,
        product: productsList[index],
        allProductsBloc: allProductsBloc,
        productType: 'ALL_PRODUCTS',
      );
    },
    separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
      return SizedBox(
        height: 16.0,
      );
    },
    itemCount: productsList.length,
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

### Solution 1 : reversed

The best solution in your case, if the list is already in ASCENDING order, would be to reverse the `productsList` at the beginning of the `build` method.

Here is the solution with a FAB to toggle the sort order:

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: MyWidget(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyWidget extends HookWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final reversed = useState(false);
    return Scaffold(
      body: MyList(
        list: List.generate(100, (index) => index.toString()),
        reversed: reversed.value,
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          reversed.value = !reversed.value;
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.sort_by_alpha),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyList extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<String> list;
  final bool reversed;

  const MyList({
    Key key,
    this.list,
    this.reversed,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final sorted = reversed ? list.reversed.toList() : list;
    return ListView.builder(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16.0, top: 16.0),
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => Card(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Text(sorted[index]),
        ),
      ),
      itemCount: list.length,
    );
  }
}
```

---

### Solution 2 : reverse: true

If it is already in ASCENDING order, you could use `reverse: true` on your `ListView`. Though, it will set the scroll position at the bottom of your `ListView`.

```
build(BuildContext context) {
  return ListView.separated(
    padding: ...,
    shrinkWrap: ...,
    reverse: true
    itemBuilder: ...,
    separatorBuilder: ...,
    itemCount: ...,
  );
}
```

---

### Solution 3 : sort()

Another solution, working even if the list was not sorted in ASCENDING order, would be to sort the `productsList` at the beginning of your `build` method.

```
build(BuildContext context) {
  productsList.sort((a, b) => b.name.toLowerCase.compareTo(a.name.toLowerCase));
  return ListView.separated(...);
}
```

*Note: I made the assumption that you want to order by name, case insensitive.*

Comment: Wow! The first 1 works but the focus on the screen is still in ascending order.

Comment: What do you mean by the focus on the screen?

Comment: The mobile screen focus is on the last when I reversed it. Using the reverse: true

Comment: I reverse it, the latest data is now on the top which is good but the mobile screen focus is on the last data now. So I need to scroll up in order to be at the top and see the latest.

Comment: Oh. Do you have any idea How I can fix the screen focus?

Comment: Instead of `List.from(productList.reversed)`, you can call `productList.reversed.toList()`.

Comment: Thanks, man but it doesn't work on my end.

Comment: Please have a look at **Solution 1**. I think that's what you want to do.

Comment: Sorry man. I want the solution 1 but I don't know how to apply to my code.

Comment: What State Management do you use? I could help if I see the full code of your widget for the list, as well as the code of the button to toggle the sort order.

Answer (score 0):

You can either call `reversed` on the sorted list or implement a custom callback to sort it in descending order.

**Using reversed**

```dart
List<String> names = ['Paul','James','Arman'];
names.sort();
print(names.reversed.toList()); // [Paul, James, Arman]
```

**Using custom implementation in sort**

```dart
List<String> names = ['Paul','James','Arman'];
names.sort((a, b) => b.compareTo(a));
print(names); // [Paul, James, Arman]
```

Comment: Error: The method 'compareTo' isn't defined for the class 'String
Function()

Comment: Example in my answer works in dartpad. Can you post what you tried?

Comment: reverse: true this it works but I have an issue on mobile focus.

Comment: I added this in the code:  reverse: true 
it works but the screen focus is not at the top or the latest.

As what the problem in this video.
https://youtu.be/CzOEx5ZYOYI?t=194

But I don't know how to apply on my code.

Comment: I meant code related to `compareTo` error.

Comment: That code in my post, I create in the dart is the output I want but I don't know how to apply.on the code I provide